# Window control for mmapped large file(linux, mmap)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mmap, large-files

How can we control the window in RSS when mapping a large file? Now let me explain what i mean.
For example, we have a large file that exceeds RAM by several times, we do shared memory mmaping for several processes, if we access some object whose virtual address is located in this mapped memory and catch a page fault, then reading from disk, the sub-question is, will the opposite happen if we no longer use the given object? If this happens like an LRU, then what is the size of the LRU and how to control it? How is page cache involved in this case?

[RSS graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teNyH.png)

This is the RSS graph on testing instance(2 thread, 8 GB RAM) for 80 GB tar file. Where does this value of 3800 MB come from and stay stable when I run through the file after it has been mapped? How can I control it (or advise the kernel to control it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're not taking explicit action to lock the pages in memory, they should eventually be swapped back out automatically. The kernel basically uses a memory pressure heuristic to decide how much of physical memory to devote to swapped-in pages, and frequently rebalances as needed.

If you want to take a more active role in controlling this process, have a look at the [`madvise()` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html).

This allows you to tweak the paging algorithm for your mmap, with actions like:

- `MADV_FREE` (since Linux 4.5)

  - The application no longer requires the pages in the range               specified by addr and len.  The kernel can thus free these               pages, but the freeing could be delayed until memory               pressure occurs. ...
- `MADV_COLD` (since Linux 5.4)

  - Deactivate a given range of pages.  This will make the               pages a more probable reclaim target should there be a               memory pressure.
- `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`

  - Expect page references in sequential order.  (Hence, pages               in the given range can be aggressively read ahead, and may               be freed soon after they are accessed.)
- `MADV_WILLNEED`

  - Expect access in the near future.  (Hence, it might be a               good idea to read some pages ahead.)
- `MADV_DONTNEED`

  - Do not expect access in the near future.  (For the time               being, the application is finished with the given range,               so the kernel can free resources associated with it.)              ...

Issuing an `madvise(MADV_SEQUENTIAL)` after creating the `mmap` might be sufficient to get acceptable behavior. If not, you could also intersperse some `MADV_WILLNEED`/`MADV_DONTNEED` access hints (and/or `MADV_FREE`/`MADV_COLD`) during the traversal as you pass groups of pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I cannot control the width of the window itself (for example, the maximum value or the minimum), right? (yes, C ++ developers want to control everything  )
That is, these 3800 MB from my example, with frequent access from different threads/processes, can generally turn into 4500 MB or even more, ideally, I would like to set a limit, for example, by 5000 MB and be sure that it will not rise above this value, and lower limit, let's say 3500MB, knowing that below this value there will be no paging upload.

Comment: If we talk about a real example, then I observe that there is a kind of "accumulation" of memory on one of the servers, and sometimes a sharp take-off when paging is loaded into the RAM and after that it is not loaded back, but the RPS on the server did not change(RPS of this problematic server is generally higher relatively other similar servers).I do not consider it reasonable to allocate more memory for the server, rather here I need to limit paging

Comment: @VladislavMarkov the details of how the kernel manages physical memory are very complicated, and heavily dependent on kernel version. See [this article for some examples](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix01/freenix01/full_papers/riel/riel_html/).

Comment: @VladislavMarkov Do you have a specific reason for wanting detailed system-wide control? `madvise` calls for your process is probably the best you can do programmatically from user-level. If you want to change the whole system's paging behavior you probably need root privileges to reconfigure your kernel, and that type of question that would better belong on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Got it, I have small question about madvice - should I call `MADV_DONTNEED/MADV_FREE` once after mmapping as setting some policy or only when I don't need the pages?
As for control - I understand that my program generally has enough memory, but page caching takes too much memory and stores the memory that, generally speaking, may not be needed soon. So LRU algorithm with the maximum cache size would fit well in my case.

Comment: Usually `MADV_DONTNEED/MADV_FREE` is called for a range of pages after the program is done using them. So in your case, the program could read the first N pages and then `madvise` the kernel to release those pages. If your're looking for something you call once at mmap time, that would be `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`, which tells the kernel to tweak the paging heuristic for sequential access.